# PCI MFA (Multi-Factor Authentication)

Tags: pci-dss

Following this link: https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pdfs/Multi-Factor-Authentication-Guidance-v1.pdf

All I understand is that:

- The intent of multi-factor authentication (MFA) is to provide a higher degree of assurance of the identity of the individual.
- The overall authentication process for MFA requires at least two of the three authentication methods described in PCI DSS Requirement 8.2

How does a Company achieve compliance PCI MFA and especially who checks this compliance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does a company achieve compliant PCI MFA?

All access from out-of-scope environments to the in-scope environment needs to use MFA. Typically, businesses deploy a jump (bastion) host in a VLAN which is accessible from the out-of-scope environment. MFA is implemented to access the jump host. Once the end user has authenticated using MFA to the jump host, they can have direct access to other in-scope systems using username/password only. Alternatively, one could implement MFA on access to any in-scope system but this is not as simple.

Who checks this compliance?

Depending on the volume of transactions your business handles and your merchant or service provider level, the validation can be through self-assessment or through on-site technical validation by a QSA. Your acquirer should indicate if you can self-assess or need an assessment by a QSA.

Answer (score 1):

> How does a Company achieve compliance PCI MFA

The most common method is to use a One Time Password (OTP).  [RSA SecurID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_SecurID) is a well-known example, and has both hard- and soft-tokens.  Hard token means a little physical device with an LCD readout that can display 6 digits.  Soft token mean a smartphone app that does the same thing.  There are numerous soft token options available these days, like [Google Authenticator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Authenticator) and [Microsoft Authenticator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/account/authenticator).

Note that for PCI compliance, MFA is only required for administrator connections.

> who checks this compliance?

Depending on the size of the organization (in $$$), either the Qualified Security Assessor (QSA) who performs the annual audit, or the organization member who fills out the Self Assessment Questionnaire (SAQ).